# Error al incluir paquete en R-studio

Tags: r

Quiero incluir unos paquetes en R-studio y me da un problema de escritura y permisos. Uso windows 10 y la version 3.2.2 de R

> install.packages(c("ggplot2"))
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library"' is not writable
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot create dir 'C:\Users\FroilÃ¡n', reason 'Permission denied'
>   Error in install.packages : unable to create ‘C:/Users/FroilÃ¡n/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   Warning message:
>   In dir.create(tempPath, recursive = TRUE) :
>     cannot create dir 'C:\Users\FroilÃ¡n', reason 'Permission denied'

Comment: Intenta abrir R o Rstudio en __modo administrador__

Comment: Leonidas ese problema es debido a la codificación de tu PC y R, a mi me pasa también en la tablet Windows que tengo al ser britanica me pasa igual que a ti. Es por el acento en tu usuario y el modo administrador no te permitirá escribir en la otra libreria. Lo único que puedes hacer es o crearte un usuario sin tilde (Porque cambiar el nombre de usuario no cambiará el nombre a la carpeta o instala los paquetes desde R como administrador, a ese le dará igual los acentos

Comment: n dir.create(userdir, recursive = TRUE) : cannot create dir 'C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\R', reason 'Permission denied'
> A mi me sucede lo mismo, pero yo no tengo acentos. Estoy usando windows 10 y la versión R 3.5.0